# Mono does not appeared to be installed error (winetricks) even though it's installed

Tags: mono, ubuntu-12.04, wine

I'm trying to install dotnet4.5 using winetricks on Ubuntu12.04 64bit. It keeps on giving me "Mono does not appear to be installed " error though I have mono installed. I ran these two commands to get mono and mono-complete

```
sudo apt-get mono-vbnc
sudo apt-get mono-complete
```

The Wine version I am using is 1.6. I have already tried reinstalling it. It's not just dotnet4.5 but all the versions of dotnet give me the same error.

I have already tried askUbuntu forums to no avail.

Comment: Please paste the full error, is it "Mono does not appear to be installed"? Or there's something more?

Comment: No , it's just Mono Does not appear to be installed . It comes as an PopUp message .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
apt-file update && sudo apt-get install `apt-file search mono.pc --package-only`
```

Comment: Doesn't work . Shows the Following ::
File is up-to-date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libmono-cil-dev is already the newest version.
libmono-cil-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 23 not upgraded.